# When to light yom tov candles?

Tags: halacha, time, yom-tov, candle-lighting

At what time should one light the candles on (the first night of) *yom tov*?

On *yom tov* it is permitted to light a fire from a pre-existing flame (unlike *shabbat*) so it seems like one could light *yom tov* candles after *yom tov* has already started.

Is there a preference to nevertheless light before *yom tov* begins, like on *shabbat*? Or maybe it's better to light closer to when the meal starts (especially if a woman wants to say *shecheyanu* in conjunction with both the candles and *kiddush*)?

Is there a latest time to light? Do the candles have to be lit before the meal starts?

Comment: It is a machloket certainly, and some follow their minhag - but consider also when a man is without his wife that he may light sooner rather than later

Comment: Wouldn’t one have the same question on the second night?

Comment: On the second night one does not have the option of lighting before the second day starts. One waits till dark to light to avoid preparing for the second day before the first day is over.

Comment: @JoelK one could light before sunset and accept the second day early, as is commonly done when Shabbat follows Yom Tov.

Comment: This is one of the two famous Halakhic positions of the Drisha's wife.

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess so in theory, although it seems to me that common practice is generally not to do so.

Comment: @Joel I agree, and to do it you'd have to be careful about various Hakahana type issues, but in principle it's possible, and some do indeed do it, like for second day Shavuot where nightfall can be very late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Aruch haShulchan in 514:17 [סימן תקיד - דיני כיבוי ביום טוב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0423_L2) writes that on Yom Tov it is not necessary to light before sunset, but in 263:12 [סימן רסג - חיוב הדלקת נרות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0181_L2) he writes that on Erev Yom Tov they usually light very close to nightfall.

Regarding your question: Is there a latest time to light? Do the candles have to be lit before the meal starts?

The Aruch haShulchan mentions in 263:12 [סימן רסג - חיוב הדלקת נרות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0181_L2) that Shabbat and Yom Tov candles have the same underlying reason, which is twofold: Light for the meal and not tripping in one's home.

It appears from what he writes in the beginning of 263 that if one lights where one eats then one can light before sunset, but if one only lights to prevent tripping (e.g. one doesn't eat at home) then it would be better to light once it's dark and one needs the light.

Thus, I understand, that as long as one can benefit from the light one may light; either until daybreak or until one goes to sleep.

(The fact that we don't actually use the candles for light, per se, is discussed by contemporary Poskim. For the meal it adds atmosphere to have candles, no matter how much electric lighting you have, but for "tripping" it may be harder to justify.)

**[סימן תקיד - דיני כיבוי ביום טוב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0423_L2)**

> **יז** המדליק נר של יום טוב צריך לברך: ''אשר קדשנו במצותיו, וציונו להדליק נר של יום טוב''. דכמו שאנו מצווין בשבת, כמו כן ביום טוב משום עונג ושמחה. ואין עונג בלא נר בלילה. ‏
> והנשים רגילות לברך ''שהחיינו'' בעת הדלקת הנרות. 
>   **וביום טוב אין צריכות להדליק מקודם**, ולכסות עיניהם ולברך כבשבת, דבשבת הוי הטעם משום דאחר הברכה הוי כקבלת שבת, ולכן מדליקות מקודם. וכדי שיהא עובר לעשייתן – מכסות עיניהן. אבל ביום טוב, דהדלקה מותר – טוב שיברכו קודם ההדלקה, כדין עובר לעשייתן ממש (דרישה ופרישה בהקדמה). ‏

**[סימן רסג - חיוב הדלקת נרות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0181_L2)**

> **יב** כשם שבשבת מצווים בהדלקת נרות, כמו כן ביום טוב, דפשיטא דיום טוב הוא זמן שמחה ואין שמחה בלא אור. ולכן צריכה לברך: ''ברוך אתה ד' אמ''ה אקב''ו להדליק נר של יום טוב''. והמרדכי והא''ז והגהמ''י הביאו זה מירושלמי, ואני לא מצאתי זה בירושלמי שלפנינו. ‏
>   ונשים שלנו מברכות גם 'שהחיינו' בעת הדלקת הנרות ביום טוב, ואין למחות בידן, דעל פי רוב **בערב יום טוב מדליקות לעת ערב ממש**, וקאי 'שהחיינו' על יום טוב. ויש מפקפקים בזה, והנח להן לבנות ישראל מנהגן. וביום הכיפורים יש מברכין ויש שאין מברכין, ואנחנו נהגנו לברך ויתבאר בסימן תר''י ע''ש. ‏

Comment: I’m not sure I agree with your reading of 514. I think he’s talking there about lighting before making the brachah, not lighting before sunset.